# IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level python во время создания голосового ассистента

Tags: python, распознавание-речи

Когда я начал писать код для создания своего голосового ассистента у меня возникла проблема при использовании библиотеки `Speech Recognition` для Python.
Ошибка:  `IndentationError: unindent does not match any outer indentation level`

Вот часть кода где возникает ошибка: `r = sr.Recognizer()`
Вот полный код на данный момент.

```
import os
import sys
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pyttsx3
import datetime

opts = {
    "alias": ('jarvis', 'jervis', 'jirves', 'jurves', 'jervas'
              'jalvis', 'jelvis', 'jilves', 'julves', 'jelvas'),
    "tbr": ('say', 'tell', 'show', 'how much', 'will', 'would',
            'could', 'may', 'can', 'must', 'the'),
    "cmds": {
        "ctime": ('current time', 'time', 'what time is it'),
        "radio": ('turn on the music', 'turn on the radio',
                  'play radio'),
        "jokes": ('tell a joke', 'do you know any jokes',
                    'make me laugh')
    }
}

# functions

def speak(what):
    print(what)
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()



#start

 r = sr.Recognizer()
 m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

 with m as source:
     r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)


speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()

speak("Good day my master")
speak("Jarvis is listening")

# stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

# while True:
#     time.sleep(0.1) # infinite loop
```

все библиотеки нормально установлены с помощью pip, все библиотеки протестированы

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`IndentationError` - ошибка, возникающая при неправильных отступах в коде.
Вот исправленный код:

```
import os
import sys
import time
import speech_recognition as sr
from fuzzywuzzy import fuzz
import pyttsx3
import datetime

opts = {
    "alias": ('jarvis', 'jervis', 'jirves', 'jurves', 'jervas'
              'jalvis', 'jelvis', 'jilves', 'julves', 'jelvas'),
    "tbr": ('say', 'tell', 'show', 'how much', 'will', 'would',
            'could', 'may', 'can', 'must', 'the'),
    "cmds": {
        "ctime": ('current time', 'time', 'what time is it'),
        "radio": ('turn on the music', 'turn on the radio',
                  'play radio'),
        "jokes": ('tell a joke', 'do you know any jokes',
                    'make me laugh')
    }
}

# functions

def speak(what):
    print(what)
    speak_engine.say(what)
    speak_engine.runAndWait()
    speak_engine.stop()



#start
r = sr.Recognizer()
m = sr.Microphone(device_index=1)

with m as source:
     r.adjust_for_ambient_noise(source)


speak_engine = pyttsx3.init()

speak("Good day my master")
speak("Jarvis is listening")

#stop_listening = r.listen_in_background(m, callback)

#while True:
#   time.sleep(0.1) # infinite loop
```

Comment: Вы хотите сказать, что ошибка возникла из-за того, что я пропустил строку после комментария start?

Comment: @E_d_u_a_r_d из-за пробелов в начале строки `r = sr.Recognizer()`. Кол-во пустых строк не играет роли.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь

Comment: @E_d_u_a_r_d отметьте ответ галочкой, если он вам помог, пожалуйста